# matplotlib axis label lost when increasing y tick labels for subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot, twinx

why are the y-axis labels lost when specifying: `ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=16)`

```
%pylab inline
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'], 'category':['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], 'foo':[10, 15, 8, 13], 'bar':[12, 8, 5, 18]})
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])

plt.figure()
ax0 = plt.subplot(211)
ax = sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='foo', data=df, hue='category', ax=ax0)
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

### edit

`plt.yticks(fontsize=16)` works just fine though. However, I must use theo object-oriented API as I use this in a more complex plot. Otherwise, `plt` refers to the wrong axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace it with:

```
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), fontsize=16)
```

A short explaination why `ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=16)` gives you empty y labels:

If you `print (ax.get_yticklabels()[:])`, it gives you:

```
[Text(1, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, '')]
```

Notice that the last item in every sublist is an empty string, they will be regarded as your ylabel.
It is thus equivalent to `ax.set_yticklabels(labels=[], fontsize=16)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `tick_params` function and specify which axis. For both axis, use `axis='both'`

```
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=16)
```